# Minor scratching on plastic fender/skirt

Tags: paint-scratches, bumper

I have minor scratching and smearing on the front skirt of my car which is the plastic part below the bumper.

Is there a way to repair this without replacing the whole skirt?

The image below shows the location:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way for you to take a photo of it and post it?  It really depends on the nuance of the damage to provide a sound recommendation.

Comment: I don't know about everyone else, but I can't see anything inside the circled area. It would help if you posted a photo of the actual damage, rather than the area.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a scratch just in the clear coat, then you can wet sand it with 2500 or 3000 grit paper and then use a buffer with a fine polish [like in this video](https://youtu.be/2nYF46P7B2c?list=PL5ZkAEzEbJ_BP6YHcuIST9XrXrRyZmdxT).

If it's more serious, like down to the plastic you'll need more aggressive sanding together with spot repainting.  [Here is a tutorial on how to do this](https://scratchwizard.net/articles/how-to-repair-your-scratched-plastic-bumper/).

Comment: Its the more agressive type, the scratch is mostly a smear, but in some areas is actually dug into the plastic to a shallow depth.

Comment: Good luck with it.  You don't have to buy the kit those guys are selling, but their tutorial is pretty good and you can just pick up everything you need at a auto paint store probably.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend a good buffing and using a soft rubbing compound. "Mother's" brand is what I usually use. Good luck